# SwiftUI Child View Width Extends Beyond Parent

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm attempting to create a `Button` width stretch to match the parent's width. I have read using `maxWidth: .infinity` will cause the view's width to match the parent view width, however my `Button`'s width extends beyond the parent view width. I have this code:

```
ZStack {
    VStack {
        // city background image
        Spacer()
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "cityscape1")!)
            .resizable()
            .renderingMode(.template)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .opacity(0.1)
            .clipped()
    }
                            
    HStack {
        ZStack {
            // display the featured icon
            AsyncImage(
                url: getImageUrl(coinBundleModel: coinBundleArray[featuredIndex]),
                content: { image in
                    image.resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 134, height: 134)
                    .clipped()
                },
                placeholder: {
                    ProgressView()
                        .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: Color("baseTint")))
                }
            )
            .cornerRadius(8)
                                    
            // featured bonus
            VStack {
                Text(getBundleDiscount(coinBundleModel: coinBundleArray[featuredIndex]))
                    .frame(width: nil, height: 20)
                    .padding(.leading, 8)
                    .padding(.trailing, 8)
                    .background(Color("miscHiLite1"))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.footnote .weight(.bold) )
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .padding(.bottom, 41)
             }
         }
         .padding(.leading, 8)
                                
         // set the featured description and purchase button
         VStack(alignment: .leading) {
             Spacer()
             // featured pack title
             Text("featured_pack")
                 .foregroundColor(.black)
                 .opacity(0.8)
                 .font(Font.system(size: 22).bold())
                 .padding(.bottom, -5)
             // featured coin count
             HStack {
                 Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "circlebadge.2")!)
                     .resizable()
                     .renderingMode(.template)
                     .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                     .foregroundColor(Color("miscHiLite1"))
                     .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                        
                 Text(self.formatCoinCount(quantity: self.coinBundleArray[featuredIndex].quantity))
                     .foregroundColor(.white)
                     .font(Font.system(size: 22).bold())
             }
             // featured bonus coins
             Text(getFeaturedBonus(coinBundleModel: coinBundleArray[featuredIndex]))
                 .foregroundColor(.black)
                 .opacity(0.8)
                 .font(Font.system(size: 16))
                                    
                                    
             // create the purchase button
             Button {
                 let product = self.store.products[featuredIndex]
                 Task {
                     await self.buy(product: product)
                 }
             } label: {
                 Text(self.store.products[featuredIndex].displayPrice)
                     .frame(
                         minWidth: 0,
                         maxWidth: .infinity,
                         minHeight: 40,
                         maxHeight: 40
                     )
                     .foregroundColor(Color("baseTint"))
                     .background(.white)
                     .clipShape(Capsule())
                     .font(Font.system(size: 16).bold())
                                            
             }
                 Spacer()
         }
         .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
         .padding(.trailing, 8)
     }
     .frame(
         minWidth: 0,
         maxWidth: .infinity,
         minHeight: 0,
         maxHeight: .infinity,
         alignment: .topLeading
     )
 }
 .frame(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: .infinity,
      minHeight: 200,
      maxHeight: 200,
      alignment: .topLeading
 )
 .background(Color("baseTint"))
```

I do know that the order is important for the `Button` properties, however I'm not seeing where I'm going wrong. As you can see from the screenshot the `Button` width is extending too far. Could anyone help point me in the right direction so I can figure out what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Don’t hard code values and use ScaledMetric if absolutely needed

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce the issue if you have local variables defined outside of your code snippet like '(Color("baseTint")' or 'UIImage(named: "cityscape1")'. I've tried your code with placeholder colors and images and saw no issues.

Comment: Agree with the above. This needs a [mre]

Comment: @LucasChae your comment did help tremendously, it made me look more at the `UIImage(named: "cityscape1")`. When I removed that image, all of the other children views were laid out properly. I was under the impression that having the `.clipped()` property would have prevented that issue. Adding                                        
    `.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)`
 fixed my issue